# unable to login remotely in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, openshift-online-2

I am very new to mysql and I want to use remote login I followed this [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684341/3985848) process but the command gives me nothing on the screen as listed on that link

```
$ lsof -i -P | grep :3306
$
```

this is the output.

*What I did so far:*
 I edited the file **/etc/mysql/my.cnf** to make change and looks like this

```
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

What I want basically that I want remote login.But I am unable to that.
I run following command on my terminal

```
$ mysql -h 127.6.110.2 -u adminTwz5PWn -p
$ enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'adminTwz5PWn'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

*For sake of information needed I got this username and password from Openshift*
 My concern is that how @'localhost' comes into the picture If I am providing the host ip in the command

I have user log in to mysql as follows

```
+------------------+---------------+
| user             | host          |
+------------------+---------------+
| root             | %             |
| root             | 127.0.0.1     |
| adminvKbP1kf     | 127.3.138.130 |
| adminTwz5PWn     | 127.6.110.2   |
| root             | ::1           |
| user             | hostname      |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost     |
| phpmyadmin       | localhost     |
| phpmyadmin_suraj | localhost     |
| root             | localhost     |
| suraj            | localhost     |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere. And what steps are needed to make this successfull

Comment: Did you restart MySQL after changing `my.cnf`? Also, is the `skip-networking` line commented out or deleted?

Comment: You will also need to grant permission to the remote user, something like `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'1.2.3.4' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;` Also check if `adminTwz5PWn` is the user name or password

Comment: @Bert I restarted mysql and `skip-networking` is not present in the file

Comment: Do you find 3306 in the output of `netstat -rn` on the server? Are there any firewall rules preventing access to that port?

Comment: @ott-- I am sorry to ask this que that how to run the command on server  I dont know how to do this

Comment: Run that command from an xterm or a console.

Comment: @ott-- [image link](http://imgur.com/RRxFr82)

Comment: My,fault, it should be `netstat -n | grep 3306`. I saw you tried port 3307 too?

Comment: @ott-- This commands returns nothing and 3307 was by mistake

Comment: Try the hints from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html - otoh it is more secure to ssh to the host and access mysql from there. For a GUI use `phpmyadmin`.

Answer (score 1):

Whole IP range `127.0.0.0/8` is reserved for loopback. Although people commonly use only `127.0.0.1`, IP `127.6.110.2` is also loopback and thus you get your "localhost error".

On your mysql server run `ip a` or `ifconfig` to find out your public IP address and then connect to that address.

You will also need to have mysql user that is allowed to connect from remote machine. Run `mysql` on your server to open mysql console and run one of these queries (change USERNAME and PASSWORD with your credentials):

To allow remote user to connect only from specific IP x.x.x.x:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

To allow remote user to connect from everywhere:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

To ensure these queries take effect, run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` then.

Comment: This is still not working.. I dont know what is my problem

Comment: Do you know public IP address of your mysql server now? Tell us first two octets - (e.g. 216.156.x.x) to determine if it's usable public IP or not.

Comment: `127.6.110.2` this is what **Openshift** gave me. and my laptop's is `192.168.1.190`